# xslt mapping using CDATA

Tags: xml, xslt

I am definitely missing something very basic so please bear with me.

Below is my XSLT:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="no" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <GenericDataSet>
            <StatementName>
                <Header action="INSERT">
                    <table>XML</table>
                    <access>
                        <XML_DATA><xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&lt;![CDATA[</xsl:text>
      <xsl:copy-of select="*"/>    
      <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">]]&gt;</xsl:text></XML_DATA>
                    </access>
                </Header>
            </StatementName>
        </GenericDataSet>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When I use the above XSLT, the source XML is copied over as-is and wrapped around CDATA tag (which is what I want).

`

```
<GenericDataSet>
   <StatementName>
      <Header action="INSERT">
         <table>XML</table>
         <access>
            <XML_DATA><![CDATA[<note>
                  <to>Tove</to>
                  <from>Jani</from>
                  <heading>Reminder</heading>
                  <body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body>
               </note>]]></XML_DATA>
         </access>
      </Header>
   </StatementName>
</GenericDataSet>`
```

However, if I simply replace &lt ; and &gt ; with < and > respectively like below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="no" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <GenericDataSet>
            <StatementName>
                <Header action="INSERT">
                    <table>XML</table>
                    <access>
                        <XML_DATA><xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes"><![CDATA[</xsl:text>
      <xsl:copy-of select="*"/>    
      <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">]]></xsl:text></XML_DATA>
                    </access>
                </Header>
            </StatementName>
        </GenericDataSet>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The output is much different.

```
<GenericDataSet>
   <StatementName>
      <Header action="INSERT">
         <table>XML</table>
         <access>
            <XML_DATA></xsl:text>
      <xsl:copy-of select="*"/>    
      <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes"></XML_DATA>
         </access>
      </Header>
   </StatementName>
</GenericDataSet>
```

Any pointers on why this is happening.?

I tried different versions of XSLT mapping, and replacing &lt ; and &gt ; with < and > gives different result.

Comment: Are you sure you want to do this? There are hundreds of posts here asking how to restore the XML inside CDATA sections.

Comment: Yeah, this is what I want to do. I am building an API that will receive an XML push (the XML structure is not known beforehand). I need to take this whole XML and insert in a single Snowflake DB table column (VARCHAR). For inserting data in Snowflake, I also need to build a wrapper around the source XML as mentioned above (StatementName, Header, table etc). I need to wrap the source XML within CDATA so that the system considers it as a data string and not an actual XML.

Comment: Well, with a XSLT 3.0 processor you can use the `serialize()` function to produce an escaped string that represents the original XML structure, without needing to fabricate a CDATA section by a DOE hack. If you're limited to XSLT 1.0, then consider: http://lenzconsulting.com/xml-to-string/

Answer (score 0):

XSLT is XML so the same rules apply. By using < and > you’re creating a CDATA section in the XSLT so anything inside of it is treated as character data (and not parsed).